# Does Throttled write events means my data is not written in database for those?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Sometimes, I get throttled events in Dynamodb because of high traffic. Whenever in the metrics, I can see throttled events, does it mean for those cases, data is not being written to the database?

Comment: yes. nothing gets written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes but, are you using an AWS SDK? If so, then it should have retried...

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadWriteCapacityMode.html)

> Throttling prevents your application from consuming too many capacity
>   units. When a request is throttled, it fails with an HTTP 400 code
>   (Bad Request) and a ProvisionedThroughputExceededException. The AWS
>   SDKs have built-in support for retrying throttled requests (see Error
>   Retries and Exponential Backoff), so you do not need to write this
>   logic yourself.

Comment: Unless of course, you are being throttled to the extent that you continually retry until the number of retries expires. Then your data is not written even if you are using the SDK.